# Google Geocoding is only running without API Key

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, api-key

I'm running Geocoding with that code, what works perfect:
$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . $address . '&sensor=false';

Problem is, it only runs with a few addresses (about 200) and then it stopps and so I have to wait 24hours to start geocoding again.

So I have created an API Key to geocode 2500 addresses a day and add it like this:
$url = http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address= . $address . &sensor=false&key=MY_API_KEY;

Problem now is, nothing happens. No address is getting geocoded. Only without an API key it works for a few addresses. I also tried different keys, with an specific referrer and without and referrer - nothing changes. Not only one address is getting geocoded.

Thanks afor help!

Answer (score 6):

Look at the error message that is returned when you call the API with a key:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=New%20York,NY&sensor=false&key=my_api_key

```
{
   "error_message" : "Requests to this API must be over SSL.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

You need to use the https: protocol.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=New%20York,NY&sensor=false&key=my_api_key

```
{
   "error_message" : "The provided API key is invalid.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem please [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)